# Update Webform and not Add if there is an existing value in one of the fields

Tags: forms, webforms

In Drupal 7, I have a field which stores Usernames of the user. If a submission is made by a user, it stores its username.

All I want is that if there's an existing submissions made by a user, and that user makes an entry in the form, the webform should update the previous entry rather than create a new one.

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this would be heavy on resources since it needs to search all 'submissions', searching for the user. An alternative idea:

- use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create a 'submission' at new user registration, setting the user as author.
- use [Node Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) to limit each user to one of that type
- use Rules to check when trying to create a new 'submission' (url contains...) and redirect to the existing 'submission' page for that user